# Ajax.load wont work when pressing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I am trying to run ajax.load method when pressing a button. The idea is very simple: change the body of a  to something else, by using the ajax.load method. However, i havent been succesful yet, and after researching for a couple of hours, i still havent found the solution. Nothing happens when i press the button.

i have tried to copy/paste one of w3schools examples into my own project, just to see if it works on my computer. The result was that it didn't work on my computer, even after changing the files in the example to my own files. this makes me think that there is a problem with how ajax has been put into the project. but i am not sure.
The example is here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load

my test-website is running on a tomcat server and is written in intelliJ. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AjaxTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $("#maincontainer").load("ajaxTestAlternativeText.txt")
    })

</script>

<div id="maincontainer">
    this text needs to change
</div>

<button id="button" type="button"> tryk her :)</button>


</body>
</html>
```

in the code above, i change the body to a .txt file. I have also tried with changing to a .html file, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. **Read the error message**.

Comment: where exactly is the .txt file located?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the Ajax call. It has to do with the fact you are binding an event to a button before the button exists on the page.... Too lazy to find the dupe.

Comment: @epascarello — That's the second problem. The first is that `$` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

One of 2 things, or you don't have jQuery installed, wich is probably the problem, or you're getting 404 error.

Get [jQuery here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js)

Change your code to:

```
$('document').ready(() => {
    $("#button").click(function () {
      $("#maincontainer").load("ajaxTestAlternativeText.txt")
    })
  })
```

Note: This will only work if you're using an actual server or localhost (like wamp, ampps, xamp...) to open your webpage because of CORS policy